# Equilateral triange, sum...

Tags: geometry, triangles

Just a short question:
In a triangle we have $\sum \left(\frac{a}{b+c}\right)^{2}$. Is the triangle equilateral?
I have derived

Comment: What are you summing over? If it is over one side ( $a$, say), then the equality doesn't follow for equilateral triangles...\

Comment: it's cyclic sum

Comment: That doesn't tell me a lot, sorry: if the triangle's sides' lengths are $\;a,b,c\;$ ,then is that sum $$\left(\frac a{b+c}\right)^2+\left(\frac b{a+c}\right)^2+\left(\frac c{a+b}\right)^2\;?$$

Comment: yes, this is the sum!

Comment: Well, then as said: **even** if the triangle is equilateral and thus $\;a=b=c\;$, the above sum then is $\;\frac34\;$ , not $\;\frac 32\;$ ...

Comment: oh sorry...it must be 3/4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all real numbers $x,y,z$ we have that
$3(x^2+y^2+z^2)\geq (x+y+z)^2$. (It follows from expanding $\sum (x-y)^2 \geq 0$)

Applying this to your sum, we have that
$\sum \left(\frac{a}{b+c}\right)^2 \geq \frac{1}{3}\left(\sum\frac{a}{b+c}\right)^2$ with equality iff $\frac{a}{b+c}=\frac{b}{c+a}=\frac{c}{a+b}$.

Now [Nesbitt's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesbitt%27s_inequality) gives that $\sum\frac{a}{b+c}\geq\frac{3}{2}$, and so we have that
$\sum \left(\frac{a}{b+c}\right)^2\geq\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2=\frac{3}{4}$.

We are given that we have equality, so we must have equality in each of the inequalities used. In particular, the equality condition for Nesbitt's Inequality is $a=b=c$ and hence the triangle is equilateral.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum\dfrac{a^2}{(b+c)^2} \geq \dfrac{(\sum \frac{a}{b+c})^2}{3} \geq \dfrac{(\frac{3}{2})^2}{3} = \dfrac{3}{4}$ by Nesbitt's inequality and Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, and equality occurs when $a = b = c$ or triangle is equilateral.